# AVAudioPlayer stop issue

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I'm using `AVAudioPlayer` in my iPhone app and it runs fine. I play an MP3 when in the `viewWillAppear` and stop it in `viewWillDisappear`. When I call `[player stop]` the sound is stopped immediately, is there a way to stop the sound slowly, as it happens when the user closes the app while the sound is still playing?

Comment: Hi Cris, you can simple use the function in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1667535/1195661) by bdebeez.

Answer (score 0):

You could slowly lower to volume until it reaches 0.
To do so you need a timer to fire off every 0.01 seconds, inside the void insert this

```
player.volume = player.volume - 0.01;
```

Now the audio slowly fades out!