# iOS how to create audio fade in/out effect in a Sprite Kit game?

Tags: ios, audio, volume, sprite-kit, objectal

I'm interested in how I can manage background music in my Sprite Kit game to achieve fade in/out.

I noticed that Sprite Kit has a built-in sound player, but it seems to be more useful for very short effects, like "on hit" sounds:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"music.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
```

It does not seem like there's a way to stop this sound.

I'm using Kobold Kit, and it comes with OALSimpleAudio library that can play sounds:

```
    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] preloadEffect:@"die.wav"];
    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"die.wav"];

    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance]preloadBg:@"battle.mp3"];
    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playBg:@"battle.mp3" loop:YES];
```

There's a  `bgVolume` property in `OALSimpleAudio`, but no real fade.

Should try to write my own fade in/out code of **if there's something out there I can use to control volume over time of a generic music player, like OALSimpleAudio**.

Comment: why don't you want to use AVAudioplayer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216581/avaudioplayer-fade-volume-out

Answer (score 4):

You can also just use the build in [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) or of course adapt the function to your player:

```
//play background sound
NSError *error;
NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SpaceLife" withExtension:@"mp3"];
self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
```

And then you add the function from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1667535/1195661):

```
- (void)doVolumeFade
{  
    if (self.backgroundMusicPlayer.volume > 0.1) {
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer.volume = self.player.volume - 0.1;
        [self performSelector:@selector(doVolumeFade) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];       
     } else {
        // Stop and get the sound ready for playing again
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer stop];
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer.volume = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is genius, simple and efective

Answer (score 3):

ObjectAL has an AVAudioPlayer wrapper built in for music playback. It's called [OALAudioTrack](http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/documentation/interface_o_a_l_audio_track.html).

OALAudioTrack has a method [`fadeTo:duration:target:selector:`](http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/documentation/interface_o_a_l_audio_track.html#ab5363744ac3a99619ca52dd2255f6d4c) that you can use to do fading. You already have an instance of OALAudioTrack available to you as the simple audio interface's `backgroundTrack` property:

```
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance].backgroundTrack fadeTo:.. duration:.. ..];
```