# Fade In, Fade Out effect in audio By using AVAssetExportSession in ios

Tags: ios, audio, avassetexportsession

I have trimmed an audio for a particular duration by using AVAssetExportSession and i am also getting the trimmed audio.

But my problem is that i want to add fade in and fade out effect in my audio.

Let me know, how can i solve this?
 Any help will be appreciated.

Code for trimming audio is here--

```
- (void)trimAudio:(NSString *)inputAudioPath audioStartTime:(float)sTime audioEndTime:(float)eTime outputPath:(NSString *)outputFilePath mode:(NSInteger)kSelectionMode
{
@try
{
    AVAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:inputAudioPath] options:nil];

    //Create the session with assets
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

    //Set the output url
    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

    // Trim video in a particular duration
    CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake((int)(floor(sTime * 100)), 100);
    CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMake((int)(ceil(eTime * 100)), 100);
    CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime);
    exportSession.timeRange = range;

    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch (exportSession.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:{
                NSLog(@"Export Complete");
                if(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(exportSession.outputURL.path)){

                    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(exportSession.outputURL.path, nil, nil, nil);
                    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(trimDidSucceed:mode:)]) {
                        [self.delegate trimDidSucceed:outputFilePath mode:kTrimAudio];
                    }
                    else{
                        [self.delegate trimDidFail:exportSession.error];
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:{
                NSLog(@"Export Error: %@", [exportSession.error description]);

                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Export Cancelled");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];


    exportSession = nil;

}
@catch (NSException * e)
{
    NSLog(@"Exception Name:%@ Reason:%@",[e name],[e reason]);
}
}
```

Comment: do you want to increase or decrease volume for some timerange in audio?

Comment: Yes, Exactly i want this.

Comment: pleae w8     @NehaPurwar i m writing

Comment: Okay @JagveerSingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//fade in /out

AVMutableAudioMix *exportAudioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *exportAudioMixInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:asset.tracks.lastObject];

int start=2,length=3;

[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolume:0.0 atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start-1, 1)];
[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolume:0.1 atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start, 1)];
[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolume:0.5 atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start+1, 1)];
[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolume:1.0 atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start+2, 1)];



[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolume:1.0 atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((start+length-2), 1)];
[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolume:0.5 atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((start+length-1), 1)];
[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolume:0.1 atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((start+length), 1)];

exportAudioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:exportAudioMixInputParameters];

exportSession.audioMix = exportAudioMix; // fade in audio mix
```

Just add these few line before     [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
}];

Comment: Thanks @Jagveer Singh

Comment: When i want to add fade in out effect in a original  audio, its adding the fade in effect after some duration of time. Can anyone resolve this??

Comment: dont get ur query, please explain . ?

Comment: Actually , i tried this on the trimmed video and its working exactly as i want but when i am applying this with my original audio , i am getting this effect after playing a part of audio rather than starting of audio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109810/discussion-between-jagveer-singh-and-neha-purwar).

Comment: if i want to just fade out for last 1.5 second so what should i change in this code? @JagveerSingh

Comment: //Suppose audio length Is 10 seconds , you want to reduce volume 1.5 before its ends

Float length= 10, start=lenth-1.5 ;

[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolume:1.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolume:0.0 atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start, 1)];
exportAudioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:exportAudioMixInputParameters];
exportSession.audioMix = exportAudioMix;

Comment: Here is my code http://dpaste.com/3GXZNSC which i have implement in Swift as per your suggestion but it not fading smoothly. @JagveerSingh

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put if statement when playing that audio by taking `nstimer` like if time reach at particular second that increase volume and if it reach at peak second then decrease  volume to initial volume.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216581/avaudioplayer-fade-volume-out) for reference.